# Recharts ScatterChart Y-Axis Problem with category

Tags: reactjs, recharts

I am having a really simple Problem but I am not able to find the solution for it.I want to change the X and Y Axis of an Rechart `<ScatterChart/>`.

Here is the Link to the Original Rechart Demo https://jsfiddle.net/alidingling/uLysj0u2/

And here is my code.

```
const {ScatterChart, Scatter, XAxis, YAxis, CartesianGrid, Tooltip, Legend} 
= Recharts;
const data = [{name: "T1", val: 100}, {name: "T2", val: 200},
              {name: "T3", val: 300}]

const SimpleScatterChart = React.createClass({
    render () {
return (
<ScatterChart width={400} height={400} margin={{top: 20, right: 20, 
    bottom: 20, left: 20}}>
    <CartesianGrid />
    <XAxis dataKey={'val'} type="number" />
    <YAxis dataKey={'name'} type="category" />
    <Scatter name='A school' data={data} fill='#8884d8'/>
  </ScatterChart>
);}})

ReactDOM.render(
  <SimpleScatterChart />,
  document.getElementById('container')
);
```

Result I want but without changed X And Y Axis: 
[image]

Result I get if I change the X And Y Axis:
[image]

It works fine if the type="number", but I need category.

Comment: is this something you want? https://jsfiddle.net/j4v6gdfo/

Comment: I guess he wants it on the Y axis not X, I think this is a bug in Recharts

Comment: its a bug https://github.com/recharts/recharts/issues/1551